# Weird pipe behavior in node's child_process?

Tags: node.js, linux, jq, child-process

I have a shell command that works fine in terminal yet when executed by node's `child_process` it errors.

Here is the command as used in terminal *([file.json](https://pastebin.com/njvSHztP) is a json file)*:

```
cat /tmp/file.json | jq
```

Here is running the same command from `child_process`:

```
var cp = require("child_process");

var command = "cat /tmp/gen_json | jq";
cp.exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  stderr ? console.log(stderr) : console.log(stdout);
});
```

Which produces:

```
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

    jq is a tool for processing JSON inputs, applying the
    given filter to its JSON text inputs and producing the
    ...
```

This is the default message that is displayed when just running `jq`. It's as if I just ran `jq` without the preceding pipe.

Comment: Not related to pipe behaviour, but you don't need `cat` here (if that's the real command you're running). Try `jq '..filter..' /tmp/file.json`.

Comment: @randomir in my case I do need `cat` because if I run `jq /tmp/file.json` it breaks with `unexpected '/'`. I don't get that error when I let `cat` parse the file before `jq`. (updated question with pastebin to json)

Comment: Looks like `jq` expects a mandatory filter, Try: `cat file | jq '.'`. This solves your other problem, also: `jq '.' file`.

Comment: @randomir I wouldn't think that would work because it is fine from terminal. But I try it and it does work. Do you want to post as an answer as that fixes my issue.

Comment: You absolutely do not need cat. That would be ridiculous to _need_ it. Anyway as randomir mentions, you _need_ to include the filter. `jq` expects a few things, input being one of them, and the filter to be performed being the other.

Comment: @JeffMercado, it turns out you don't always need to include the filter, only when output goes to non-TTY. I was stumped because I knew previous versions of `jq` always required the filter.

Comment: @randomir: hmm, interesting, I thought the same to. Thanks for pointing that out. That being said, I think you would agree that it's still not a necessary use of cat, just to be able to omit the filter.

Comment: @JeffMercado, of course I agree, especially since you can write `jq <file` to get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch is in `jq`'s [attempts to intelligently infer the default filter](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1110), if the filter was omitted.

Namely, when output goes to a **terminal** (TTY), the **filter may be omitted**, and it defaults to `.` (pretty print). That's why in terminal you can write:

```
cat file | jq           # or:  jq < file
```

instead of:

```
cat file | jq .         # or:  jq . file
```

When invoked from `node`, however, with `stdin` and **`stdout` redirected**, `jq` **requires the filter** argument. That's why you have to specify it explicitly:

```
var command = "cat /tmp/gen_json | jq .";
```

or, even better (to avoid the feline abuse):

```
var command = "jq . /tmp/gen_json";
```

Comment: `jq ‘.’` can be simplified to: `jq .`